# Problema com validação JavaScript

Tags: javascript, validação

Gostaria de uma ajuda pra saber o que há de errado com essa validação:

```
if(qtdemp=5 && func1.value.length == 0 || cpf1.value.length == 0 || func2.value.length == 0 || cpf2.value.length == 0 || func3.value.length == 0 || cpf3.value.length == 0 || func4.value.length == 0 || cpf4.value.length == 0 || func5.value.length == 0 || cpf5.value.length == 0){
    mgs +="Nome e CPF do(s) Funcionário(s) obrigatórios<br/>";
}
```

A intenção é verificar se `qtdemp=5` e se os campos `func1` ou `cpf1` ou `func2` ou `cpf2` ou `func3` ou `cpf3` ou `func4` ou `cpf4` ou `func5`  ou `cpf5` estão vazios.

Validações semelhantes (se `func1` = `func2` por exemplo) também são feitas em seguida.

Sempre que ativo essas validações dá erro no meu código (em uma parte que não tem nada a ver com isso). É só tirá-las que funciona a gravação.

Comment: qntdemp só tem um sinal de igual, ou seja, invés de verificar se é igual, ele está setando o valor 5.

Comment: Alem do que o @ClaydersonFerreira disse, se sua intenção é disser que `qtdemp` deve ser `5` e mais alguma das outras opções, então estas deve estar entre parenteses. `if(qtdemp==5 && (true || false || true || true)){}`

Comment: Guilherme, tentei fazer isso de colocar o == (realmente tinha esquecido), mas mesmo colocando os parenteses não consegui fazer a validação!
Se eu deixar essa validação junto com as outras que validam campo em branco, ele dá erro em uma conversão (que é feita após essas validações).
Se eu mudar de lugar pra depois dessa conversão, ele nem passa por dentro da função.
Pela lógica se eu escrevesse:
    if(empregados==1 && (func1.value.length == 0 || cpf1.value.length == 11)){
  mgs +="Nome e CPF do Funcionário obrigatórios<br/>";
 }
Deveria funcionar né?

Answer (score 1):

mmooser, tente colocar todos os funcionarios em um array, então utilize funções como `sort`, `some`, `every`, `reduce` para realizar as verificações.

```js
var nonNumeric = /[^0-9]/g;
var funcs = [];

var validar = function () {
  //normalizando entrada de dados, 
  //removendo espaços desnecessarios do nome do funcionario
  //e caracteres não numericos do CPF.
  var normalizado = funcs.map(function (func, indice) {
    if (!func.desc) func.desc = "";
    if (!func.cpf) func.cpf = "";    
    func.desc = func.desc.trim();
    func.cpf = func.cpf.replace(nonNumeric, "");
    return func;
  });
  
  //verificando se todos os funcionarios foram preenchidos.
  var semDados = normalizado.some(function (func, indice) { 
    return !func.desc || !func.cpf || func.cpf.length != 11;
  });
  
  //ordenando por CPF.
  normalizado.sort(function (funcA, funcB) { 
    return funcA.cpf > funcB.cpf ? 1 : funcA.cpf < funcB.cpf ? -1 : 0;
  });

  //verificando se há repetição de CPF.
  var repetidos = normalizado.reduce(function (repetido, atual, indice, funcs) {
    var proximo = funcs[indice+1];
    if (!proximo) 
      return repetido;    
    return repetido || atual.cpf == proximo.cpf;
  }, false);

  console.log({ qtd: funcs.length, semDados: semDados, repetidos: repetidos });
};

funcs.push({ desc: "João",   cpf: "332.353.141-80" });
funcs.push({ desc: "Maria",  cpf: "811.672.633-16" });
funcs.push({ desc: "José",   cpf: "954.875.167-40" });
funcs.push({ desc: "Sophia", cpf: "444.765.147-58" });
validar();

// inserindo um novo João, porém com um CPF diferente.
funcs.push({ desc: "João",   cpf: "551.812.471-64" });
validar();

// inserindo um novo José, porém com o mesmo CPF, alterando apenas a formatação.
funcs.push({ desc: "José",   cpf: "95487516740" });
validar();

//tentativa de inserir funcionando sem nome e sem documento.
funcs.push({ desc: "   ",   cpf: "..-" });
validar();
```

na primeira validação, verificado se foi informado um Nome para o funcionario e se o mesmo não é uma string vazia, também verifico o mesmo para o CPF e se o mesmo possui 11 numeros.

após verificar se todas as entradas foram preenchidas, verifico se todos os CPFs informados são unicos.

fazendo desta forma, você não deverá ter problemas, além do fato que funcionará para qual quer numero de funcionarios.

Comment: Toby, acho que essa validação é muita coisa pra mim! Pois não ultrapassa o limite de 5 nomes e 5 cpfs.
Eu sou totalmente novata em programação, estou quebrando galho!
Obrigada mesmo assim!!!!